# Why are there random clicks when using KVM switch?

Tags: mouse, kvm-switch

Using a new CKLau KVM switch, occasionally there are random mouse clicks on the screen. These clicks only occur one one of the computers and not both. The clicks are very frustrating; they move the cursor while typing or pop up a context menu. Sometimes the problem goes away when power-cycling the KVM, but it is not consistent.

System:

- **CKLau 2-Port DisplayPort KVM Switch**
- Windows 10
- Logitech M510 Mouse
- Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000

Should I just return the KVM and get another?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by another pointing device and has nothing to do with the KVM.

Steps to address:

1. Open Device Manager and expand "Mice and other pointing devices".
2. Note how many "HID-compliant mouse" devices appear. If there is more than one, another pointing device can be introducing clicks.
3. Click the "Mice and other pointer devices" entry to select it.
4. Unplug the mouse and wait until one of the "HID-compliant mouse" entries disappears.

   - If that was the only entry, go to step 6.
   - If there are still more entries, continue to step 5.
5. Using the keyboard, use "arrow-down" key to select the remaining entries one-at-a-time and press "delete" and uninstall them.
6. After there are no more entries under "Mice and other pointing devices", plug the mouse back in. Windows will detect it and re-install the driver for it.

Comment: The cultprit turned out to be a 15-year-old graphics tablet that began to emit random clicks. It was plugged directly into the system that showed the random clicks and was not plugged into the hub ports on the CKLau KVM switch.